# Execute command on file system events

Tags: linux, debian, command-line-interface, filesystems

Hey there, does anyone know how to execute a command whenever a file system change occures within a given directory? I'm running Debian 6.0 and would like to call "make html" when a file/directory was eiter added or modified.

[Swatch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/swatch) seems to be what I want but it throws syntax errors.

Comment: [Another answer on superuser](http://superuser.com/a/363513/102954) for a [very similar question](http://superuser.com/q/363511/102954).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [inotify](http://www.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Inotify).  Specifically, you can use [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/).  See [the example shell scripts](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/#info) for some example usage.

Also see [incron](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/144666/) as a relatively easy way to fire off a script in reaction to a change in a directory.

If you're running Debian 6.0, `apt-get install incron` should work to get incron installed for your use if you don't have it already.

Comment: Thank you, this line did the job: `while true; do inotifywait -e modify /path/to/directory/ && make; done`

Comment: ah yes, I should have included the exact usage as you did give enough info in your initial question.  Glad it worked!

Comment: Link to `incron` broken. [Here's a possible replacement](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=common&page=news&lang=en)